# Как оптимизировать памть в php, в частности в Bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс, оптимизация

Для реализации одного крупного проекта был выбран Bitrix (давайте опустим холивары), столкнулся с проблемой, что phpunit съедает больше 500 мб, пришлось поднять memory_limit до 1 гб, а при обычной работе пришлось поднять до 512 мб, т.к. иногда php падал с ошибкой. В резльутате чего решил проверить, что так сильно ест память, поставил php-memory-profiler, снял дамп, при выполнении юнит тестов, и там вот такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по картинке, основное, что съедает память, является Автолоудеры классов или какие-то дургие участки кода, которые подключают всякие большие справочники для работы. Отсюда вопрос, есть ли возможности оптимизации памяти, или это данность монолита?

Comment: Возможность оптимизации памяти есть. Это не данность монолита, наоборот, в среднем по больнице монолит занимает меньше памяти, т.к. в нем нет издержек на межсервисное взаимодействие. Это данность Битрикса и в целом продукции 1С.

Comment: Это данность битрикса. Некоторые класс там могут быть со статическими полями, которые накапливают данные. Делалось в расчете на веб (отработал - умер). А при тестах у вас скорей всего эти данные не обнуляются